Apache Ignite deserializes class with writeReplace/readResolve methods during BinaryObject creation
I am storing in Ignite cache an object that contains a field of type org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology .
The ISOChronology is a 3rd party class having writeReplace() and readResolve() methods.
The cache is using the binary format, i.e. IgniteCache.withKeepBinary() and uses an EntityProcessor. The object is initially serialized using BinaryObjectBuilder on client side and passed as an argument to the processor. Processor receives the BinaryObject, calls toBuilder() and modifies some fields. The ISOChronology field is not modified. Then, BinaryObjectBuilder.build() is called to serialize the modified value and fails. For some reason, it tries deserializing ISOChronology before serializing it again, and this class is not available on the server.
The error is:
org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to unmarshal object with optimized marshaller
Why does BinaryObjectBuilder deserializes a BinaryObject before serializing it again ? There is a warning in documentation about the fact that Externalizable objects are deserialized, it seems related:
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/key-value-api/binary-objects#enabling-binary-mode-for-caches
Still, not sure why this is done and how to avoid it. Any insights ?
Expected:
Calling BinaryObjectBuilder.build() with field containing BinaryObject is expected to succeed without deserializing the field.
Actual:
The operation fails trying to deserialize ISOChronology value.
Processor Implementation:
public class TestBinaryProcessor implements EntryProcessor<String, BinaryObject, Boolean>  {

    @IgniteInstanceResource
    private Ignite ignite;

    private static final String MAP_FIELD_NAME = "map";
    private static final String BINARY_TYPE = TestBinaryProcessor.class.getName() + ".value";

    @Override
    public Boolean process(MutableEntry<String, BinaryObject> entry, Object... arguments) throws EntryProcessorException {

        BinaryObject entryValue = entry.getValue();
        String key = (String) arguments[0];
        BinaryObject value = (BinaryObject) arguments[1];

        Map<String, BinaryObject> map = entryValue != null ? entryValue.field(MAP_FIELD_NAME) : new HashMap<>();

        map.put(key, value);

        BinaryObjectBuilder binaryObjectBuilder = entryValue != null ? entryValue.toBuilder() : ignite.binary().builder(BINARY_TYPE);
        binaryObjectBuilder.setField(MAP_FIELD_NAME, map);

        entry.setValue(binaryObjectBuilder.build());

        return true;
    }
}

Processor Invocation:
Cache<String, BinaryObject> cache = ignite.cache("default").withKeepBinary();
return cache.invoke("testMap", new TestBinaryProcessor(), "testKey", ignite.binary().toBinary(org.joda.time.DateTime.now()));


Can you please share your code?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
